# No wifi connection after bootup, again

Tags: wifi, boot-issues

Another "Raspberry doesn't connect to Wifi after bootup", but I'm out of ideas. Hopefully not too annoying, guys:

Raspberry runs regular debian wheezy, system is updated. I use a RT5370 USB wifi connection, drivers are updated. Wireless powermanagement shows up as off.

When booting up just with the Wifi connected (no eth0), i can't ping anything outside the raspberry. Using `ifdown wlan0 --force` and `ifup wlan0 --force` doesn't give me any change. 
When I connect the LAN cable, eth0 works as expected. 
Umplugging the LAN cable leads to the wifi coming up as expected, which seems to show the general settings of the wifi are correct.

I've tried all combinations of auto / allow-hotplug wlan0 in `/etc/network/interfaces`.

I've read tons of stuff how to resolve this, tried different setups, no result. I installed a new testing debian on a different machine with another usb wifi dongle of the same kind, the behavious is the same. Probably it's an easy solution, but I'm blocked.

`/etc/network/interfaces` looks like this

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.2.202
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.2.1

auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual

wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

wireless-power off

iface extreme inet dhcp
    address 192.168.2.203
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.2.1

iface office inet static
    address 192.168.2.203
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.2.1
```

`/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` looks like this

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
    ssid="ssid1"
    scan_ssid=1
    psk="password1"
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    id_str="extreme"
    priority=15
}
network={
    ssid="ssid2"
    scan_ssid=1
    psk="password2"
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    id_str="office"
    priority=2
}
```

ifconfig for wlan0 before unplugging the network cable

```
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:87:35:1c:68:27  
      inet addr:192.168.2.203  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

ifconfig for wlan0 after unplugging the network cable

```
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:87:35:1c:68:27  
      inet addr:192.168.2.203  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:5078 errors:0 dropped:308 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:295 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:747609 (730.0 KiB)  TX bytes:45009 (43.9 KiB)
```

iwconfig after bootup

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any 
      Mode:Managed  Access Point: Non-Associated Tx-Power=20 dBm   
      Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:off
```

iwconfig after unplugging the network cable

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"ssid1"  
      Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: B8:C7:5D:02:DC:3D   
      Bit Rate=65 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
      Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:off
      Link Quality=41/70  Signal level=-69 dBm  
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:2  Invalid misc:109   Missed beacon:0
```

Comment: Since it is the one thing not mentioned in your question I will ask how are you powering the Pi? are you using a powered hub to connect the wifi dongle?

Comment: Directly on the Pi. Would that make a difference, as wifi connects after unplugging the ethernet cable?

Comment: It might - the greatest demand is likely on startup, demand falls once the system is up. If you look around at the other wifi questions and the diagnostic thread on elinux and the Pi forums this seems to be a common source of problems.

Comment: I tried using a powered USB hub, no change.